# How can I bold some of the texts in a dynamic text column in a measure

Tags: powerbi

I want to bold some of my texts in a dynamic text column that I have created, I want to keep the rest of the text unbold. I have created a measure for the same.

I am getting the dynamic output but want some of the texts as bold

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I know of two options. You could use the text box which allows for bolding and some smart visuals. You could alternatively use the HTML5 Custom Visual outlined here:

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Part-of-text-to-be-bold-using-DAX/td-p/492204